# Set timeout for Android Download manager after 2 min

Tags: android, download, android-download-manager

How to set the Download manager time out and enable or disable the Download manager after 2 minutes.

```
fun downloadFile(url: String) {
  val downloadManager = this.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager

            val downloadUri = Uri.parse(url)

            val request = DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri).apply {
                try {
                    setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI or DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                        .setAllowedOverRoaming(true)
                        .setTitle(url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1))
                        // .setDescription("abc")
                        .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
                        .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                            url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
                        )
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }

            }
            //TODO to get the Downloading status
            val downloadId = downloadManager.enqueue(request)
            val query = DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(downloadId)

}
```

In above code how to handle the timeout with download manager.

Comment: Kindly share some code that you might have done

Comment: Apart from your timeout problem: your code will not work. Did it?

Comment: @blackapps if any failure in API need stop the download manager or if download manger stands for more than a minute pending or paused need to stop

Comment: Repeat: Your code will not work. Did it?

Comment: You can remove that mkdirs() call as the download manager will create that folder for you.

Comment: On Android 11+, and maybe also lower, the download manager will not download to your subfoldet as it is not one of the usual public folders. You will get an error message saying so. So how does your code work?

Comment: @blackapps I have Modified my code. here can we add time out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can schedule a new thread to run after x milliseconds using Handler.postDelayed(); In that scheduled thread you use would use DownloadManager.query to access the Cursor object which exposes the download status. If the download status indicates the download isn't completed successfully, you can cancel it using DownloadManager.remove()

I tested that this works:

```
private fun tryDownloadFileButCancelIfTimeout(url: String, millisecondsToTimeoutAfter : Long) {
    val downloadManager = this.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
    val downloadUri = Uri.parse(url)
    val request = DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri).apply {
        try {
            setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI or DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                .setAllowedOverRoaming(true)
                .setTitle(url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1))
                .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE)
                .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                    url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
                )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
    val downloadId = downloadManager.enqueue(request)
    // Schedule a new thread that will cancel the download after millisecondsToTimeoutAfter milliseconds
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
        val downloadQuery = DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(downloadId)
        val cursor = downloadManager.query(downloadQuery)
        val downloadStatusColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)
        cursor.moveToPosition(0)
        val downloadStatus = cursor.getInt(downloadStatusColumn)
        if (downloadStatus != DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
            downloadManager.remove(downloadId)
        }

    }, millisecondsToTimeoutAfter)
}
```

Posting the code I used to test (can import to Android Studio if you like, simple app with a single download button that starts the download and cancels in five seconds):

https://github.com/hishamhijjawi/DownloadCancelDemoStackOverflow